# Why use K-medoids for sequence analysis?

Tags: clustering, k-means, sequence-analysis, traminer, k-medoids

In the package `WeightedCluster` there seems to be facilities for using K-medoids clustering (i.e. `wcKMedoids()`), but not the more common K-means. Some traditional recommendations of clustering specify that first one should determine the number of clusters using agglomerative clutering, e.g. Ward, and then create a final solution using K-means (Punj & Stewart, 1995).

Hence my question: why would K-medoids be more suitable than K-means for sequence analysis?

**References**

Punj, G., and Stewart, D. W. 1995. “Cluster Analysis in Marketing Research: Review and Suggestions for Application,” Journal of Marketing Research (20:2), pp. 134–148.

Comment: Don't treat a *marketing* paper as authorative on whether to use k-means. Most likely, they simply never had heard of anything else...

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "sequence analysis"?

Comment: @whuber: Analyzing sequences using the `TraMineR` package. I guess the more appropriate question would be why data in the form of sequences might be better suited for K-medoids compared to K-means. I suspect the answer is that there is no "mean" sequence, but there is a medoid sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard K-means is intended for numeric data and is not directly applicable to other types of objects such as categorical sequences (see for example at [that question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data).)

In sequence analysis, we generally compute pairwise dissimilarities between sequences using one of many possible different metrics (See [1] for a review.) Although we do not know what the mean of a cluster of sequences could be, we can express the distance to the (virtual) mean of the cluster in terms of pairwise distances between the cluster members (See for instance  [2, page 478]). In this way, k-means should be applicable whenever we have a pairwise dissimilarity matrix. Nevertheless, for categorical sequences, pairwise-dissimilarity-based k-medoids is much easier to implement and should be much faster.

Now, regarding the choice of the number k of clusters. I don't think that determining k from the solution of a hierarchical clustering is the best way to proceed. Exploring the k-medoids solutions for a range of k values is much more efficient and it is very easily done with the `wcKMedRange` function of the  `WeightedCluster` R library that returns a whole series of cluster quality measures for the requested set of values k.

---

[1]  Studer, M., and Ritschard, G. (2016) "What Matters in Differences between Life Trajectories: A Comparative Review of Sequence Dissimilarity Measures", *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series A*. Vol. 179(2), pp. 481-511 DOI [10.1111/rssa.12125](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/rssa.12125).

[2] Studer, M., Ritschard, G., Gabadinho, A. & Müller, N.S. (2011), "Discrepancy Analysis of State Sequences", *Sociological Methods and Research*. Vol. 40(3), pp. 471-510. DOI [10.1177/0049124111415372](http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0049124111415372)